# Formal way to say "Somehow"

Tags: word-usage, word-request, formal-language

I wrote this sentence. (excuse me for the repeated sentence)

> However, if the user **somehow could** specify the context necessary to apply the rule (e.g. the page sidebar),then before removing such an element, context would be considered.

How can I say such phrases more formally, maybe:

> if it was possible for the user to specify ....

Comment: There's no need for it; *could* implies possibility.

Comment: @StoneyB yes, I thought of it too, but are there situation that a formal word is needed?

Comment: And "*if it **were** possible*", in case it's mostly hypothetical.

Comment: @VictorBazarov thanks, then it is "if it were..." that suits my need

Comment: @VictorBazarov Possibly consider editing your answer to include all information you've given in the comments, to increase the chance of having an answer Ahmad can fully accept. :)

Comment: @TechnikEmpire: Some of us here are not after the ratings...

Comment: In my opinion as a software developer @Ahmad, it sounds to me like you're not struggling with language, but rather struggling with clearly defining the guaranteed behavior of an API. If the user isn't supposed to be able to do something, except for limited checks to avoid crashes, don't write any code to handle a situation that your software does not promise to handle.

Comment: @VictorBazarov It's not about getting ratings, it's about following the format of the website to provide an acceptable answer to a question. If the gold part of your answer lies in comments, but not in your official answer, then it robs Ahmad of the ability to accept the answer, thus closing the topic. Unanswered questions stay in the cue, and can be dragged up by the community to fish for an answer. Plus, it wasted the time of people following the "unanswered" tag.

Comment: My comment about using "***were***" instead of "***was***" was aimed to suggest an edit to his question, not to give an answer.  I actually don't consider "*if it were possible*" decent enough to put in a manual (in that context, anyway).

Comment: @TechnikEmpire Thank you very much for advice, however it is not a software exactly, it is an article in which I am describing a scenario which is not covered by existing techniques

Comment: @Ahmad woops, sounded like software dev. :)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that it is not possible for the user to "specify the context", talking about doing that is a *contrafactual* situation, which calls for the *subjunctive*.

- If the user were {able/allowed) to specify the context. . .

Answer (score 0):

Try

> However, should the user specify the context necessary to apply the rule before removing an element, that context would be considered.

Comment: This answer implies that there is a mechanism by which the user can perform the actions ("Specify the context..."). The original post proposes a situation in which there is no known way to perform the action, but that it might be desirable to do so.

Answer (score 0):

I would say *somehow* is not needed here, depending on the context though.

By using *somehow*, the writer is indicating that the user might have a difficult time doing the requested action. Also I would switch the word order to be more natural (keeping the adverb next to the verb).

> However, if the user **could somehow** specify the context necessary to apply the rule (e.g. the page sidebar), then before removing such an element, context would be considered.

You could use *possible* but I don't see any benefit. *could/can* seems better to me.

Comment: And that is my purpose, because the application doesn't let him do

Comment: 'Somehow could' is different to just 'could'. You can say to someone (filling out a form on screen for example) "If you could select 'Free delivery'" which is a polite way of requesting someone to perform an action. However, "If you could somehow select 'Free Delivery'" which implies that Free Delivery would be a desirable outcome, but that the mechanism to select it is not known and may not be available.